# UK transit visa for Greek resident permit holder

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, transit, nigerian-citizens

I have called and mailed different offices including the UK embassy in Greece concerning this question, I have one office directing me to another in circle.
Anyway, I have a 5years Greek resident permit, I'm travelling to Lagos, Nigeria using the British airways, I'm a Nigerian passport holder. Now some people say I need a transit visa and some say I do not, does anyone have an idea to give me a correct answer?
I'm not getting out of the airport as it's just few hours in transit.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/nigeria/transit/no

You do not need a transit visa.

Comment: Could you quote the relevant part from the link? That way if the link dies, we still have the useful info.